# How to Configure Breeze Web API Controller for Both Windows and Web Clients

Tags: c#, odata, breeze, breeze-sharp

We are already having the Breeze Web API Controller for our Existing Web Client Application.Its is working smoothly. Now we need to add one more client for Windows Application.Can we use the same Breeze controller for windows application.

I have read through your Breeze web site and found you gave an option like

> You won't have to write the server twice. Rather you wrap the same
>   core server logic in two separate lightweight controller sets - one
>   Breeze controller and one small, focused set of OData controllers.

Can you please explain how can we archive this process. Also, Please provide a sample application will helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same server-side controllers for a Breeze# application that you use for a BreezeJS application.  Ignore the OData stuff - WebAPI controllers work for both clients without using OData.